# PHP & .htaccess redirection loop [does header(location: url) consult .htaccess?]

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm currently forwarding all requests to a single `.php` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ urls.php [L,QSA]
```

For simplicity, lets say the `urls.php` page is as follows:

```
<?php
    if(condition) {
        header( "Location: index.php" );
    } else {
        header( "Location: somewhere.php" );
    }
    die();
?>
```

When a request is made, it enters a redirect loop, I assume this is because it's a never ending loop from `urls.php` to the page it redirects to and back again.

**Questions:**

-> Does the `header()` function always consult the `.htaccess` file, or is there a way to skip it and go directly to the url?

-> If it always consults it, is there a different PHP approach that I could use to achieve what I want?

Comment: no it is the other way around.
your htaccess say that ALL requests in this directory will be redirected to urls.php. and this INCLUDE the urls.php. so it makes no sense to reference in htaccess to the urls.php in wich you define another redirect ...

Comment: interesting, so you're saying if I exclude `urls.php` from my `.htaccess` file, everything should work as intended?

Comment: it would be make sense if in this destination file where the user is referenced from htaccess there isn't another redirect. so you can reference all your requests to index.php instead of urls.php. delete this urls.php file, and you have your solution

Comment: No but the reason I'm redirecting to one page is that the `urls.php` will perform the logic necessary to distinguish where to redirect the page. see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every HTTP request makes the server read the .htaccess file.


To answer your questions:

1. Yes, `header()` outputs an HTTP 301 header which generates another request.
2. **SOLUTION** is to `include()` the corresponding page instead of redirecting to it using`header()`.

**Note:**
As *@goldlife* pointed out in a comment, your rule and page together generate a loop because:

1. `url.php` redirects to `index.php` using the `header()` function
2. `index.php`, in turn, is rewritten by your `.htaccess` to `url.php`

To break this loop, you should drop one of the two operations (I vote for dropping the first one).

Comment: The point of the redirecting to `urls.php` is to perform the logic there to distinguish where to go next. See my updated question.

Comment: This logic will still generate a loop if used together with your rewrite rule. It should be implemented all in one place (.htacces OR urls.php).

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions and `include()` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirect you should you should extract url and route accordingly by using 'include' function.  You can apply your logic before routing.